# ffmpeg doesn't write file in docker

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

Goal - Generate video file from PNGs.

```
command: ffmpeg 
args: [
  "-nostdin",
  "-v",
  "error",
  "-stats",
  "-hide_banner",
  "-y",
  "-f",
  "lavfi",
  "-i",
  "color=c=black:size=1080x1350",
  "-f",
  "image2pipe",
  "-c:v",
  "png",
  "-r",
  "25",
  "-i",
  "-",
  "-filter_complex",
  "[0:v][1:v]overlay[o];[o]scale=1080:-2:flags=bicubic[out]",
  "-map",
  "[out]",
  "-c:v",
  "libx264",
  "-profile:v",
  "main",
  "-preset",
  "medium",
  "-crf",
  "20",
  "-movflags",
  "faststart",
  "-pix_fmt",
  "yuv420p",
  "-r",
  "25",
  "-frames:v",
  "175",
  "/Users/tk/projects/lottie-to-mp4/files/xv-DIcVz0rYPZjXalgrnzmkPbqHLe9_generated.mp4"
]
```

Works in local machine (MAC)
Doesn't work in docker.

After ffmpeg finishes I make a log

```
fs.statSync(videoFilePath).size
```

In local the log gives 3286531, but in docker it's alway 48.

I create path to video like this:

```
const relevantPath = "../../files";    
const videoFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, relevantPath, `${ generatedFileName }_generated.mp4`);
```